# Cannot update SQL table value using SET

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have tried many different forms of syntax, and no matter what I use, I cannot get the boolean **logged_in** in my SQL database to change.

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>User Login Form - PHP MySQL Login System</h1>
    <?php
    if (!isset($_POST['submit'])){
    ?>
    <!-- The HTML login form -->
    <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>

    <?php
require_once("settings.php");
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
# check connection
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
exit();
}

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = sha1($_POST['password']);

$sql = "SELECT * from Users WHERE username LIKE '{$username}' AND password LIKE '{$password}' LIMIT 1";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows == 1) {

#update the logged_in value here
$sql2 = "UPDATE Users SET logged_in = 1 WHERE username = '$username'";

$location = "contacts.php";
header("Location: $location");
} else {
$location = "login.php";
header("Location: $location");
}
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I successfully log in using my **settings.php**:

```
<?php
    # mysql db constants DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME
    const DB_HOST = 'localhost';
    const DB_USER = 'Timmy';
    const DB_PASS = 'mypassword';
    const DB_NAME = 'IT210';
?>
```

but the **logged_in** value remains the same:
[image]

Comment: replace $result = $mysqli->query($sql); with $result = $mysqli->query($mysqli,$sql);

Comment: Your data is not committed. Or you use autocommit ?

Comment: @velkoon and update $sql2 = "UPDATE Users SET logged_in = 1 WHERE username = '$username'"; with $sql2 = $mysqli->query($mysqli,"UPDATE Users SET logged_in = 1 WHERE username = '$username'");

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. This has many dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) since you didn’t [properly escape values](http://bobby-tables.com/php). This code allows *anyone* to get *anything* from your site. **DO NOT** write your own authentication system. Any [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication) built-in.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Using an extremely weak hash like SHA1 to encode passwords is a really bad idea. Use something like [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) at the absolute minimum and read up on proper [password hashing](http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing) to learn more.

Comment: @tadman Thank you for the kind suggestions and pointers. Unfortunately, this is work for a college assignment with specific requirements, such as sha1 passwords and writing our own authentication. I would certainly apply any tips to make my site more secure and efficient if I were developing on my own

Comment: Best of luck getting through this assignment then. I really wish colleges would update their curriculum to something relevant from the last decade.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this

```
#update the logged_in value here
$sql2 = "UPDATE Users SET logged_in = 1 WHERE username = '$username'";
$mysqli->query($sql2);
```

You are missing Execute update query.  ( $mysqli->query($sql2);)

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't have a Valentine today, so be mine? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql2 = "UPDATE Users SET logged_in = 1 WHERE username = '{$username}'";
```